# In which file does Chromium store session storage data of the HTML5 webstorage

Tags: chrome, storage, session

I am trying to find the file where Chromium stores the session storage. In `~/.config/chromium/Default/Session Storage` there are a few files which seem promising:

```
user@desktop-04:~/.config/chromium/Default/Session Storage$ ls -hl
total 44K
-rw------- 1 user students2016 33K Mar 10 13:25 000005.ldb
-rw------- 1 user students2016  5K Mar 10 13:50 000005.log
-rw------- 1 user students2016   0 Mar 10 13:12 LOCK
-rw------- 1 user students2016 284 Mar 10 13:25 LOG
-rw------- 1 user students2016  97 Mar 10 13:25 MANIFEST-000001
```

I can find the key/value pairs in the `000005.log` but that is just the log. Not the actual file that stores the information. Inspecting other files doesn't show me the data that is in Chromiums session storage. Is suspect it to be in `000005.ldb`. But don't know how to access it. I did a hexdump on it which didn't give me any useful information.

Does anyone know in which file exactly the session storage is stored and maybe also knows with which tool I can access it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=leveldb%20log

https://www.quora.com/Why-does-a-LevelDB-database-use-a-directory-instead-of-a-single-file

> New writes are first appended to a binary log file and cached in memory, and when this log file grows to a certain size (default is a few megabytes), it's contents are converted into an SSTable file.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LevelDB

> LevelDB is used as the backend database for Google Chrome's IndexedDB.

http://leveldb.org/

> maybe also knows with which tool I can access it?

https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14409/leveldb-database-client

Comment: You don't say much, but what you say is pure gold.